# Multiple JQuery hovercards on one page

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-hover

I am using the `jQuery Hovercard` plugin [(here)](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/Hovercard) and trying to impliment it with user images pulled from `Facebook` with their php sdk, here is the code I am using to display the Hovercard:

```
<?php 
    $friends = $this->facebook->api('/me/friends');
    foreach ($friends["data"] as $value) { ?>
        <label id="demo-facebook" data-hovercard="<?php echo $value['id'] ?>">
            <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $value["id"] ?>/picture" alt="<?php echo $value["name"] ?>" />
        </label>
    <?php }
?>
```

The problem I am having is that the Hovercard will only show for the first users image displayed, after that no Hovercard will show when the image is moused over ?

Comment: You're re-using the same ID value over and over. Modify it to use the class attribute instead: `class='demo-facebook'`. Then change your selector to check for a class rather than an ID.

Comment: You can not use the same ID for more than one element within one HTML document … absolute HTML basics, dude …

Answer (score 0):

You should change the CSS selector "demo-facebook" from an id to a class. I haven't used HoverCard before, but that seems like it would be the problem.

An ID specifies one specific element of a page, whereas a class can be re-used on multiple elements.

Also, I think it would be easier to just echo the HTML instead of having a `<?php echo $value; ?>` everytime you have to insert a PHP value. You could just do `echo "<img src='$value'>";` instead of `<img src="<?php echo $value; ?>" />`. Just seems like it would be easier that way.

Comment: Gooed answer. About the HTML/PHP mixing: this seems to bealmost a religious debate and seems to me more a question of taste than best practice. Although others will likely disagree on that... ;-)